# convert text string to hexadecimal representation or binary representation

Tags: sql-server

hello guys simple question that i seemed to be stumped on. I have something that seems to work but i get a blank result.
I have a text string in a column in a database. for the sake of this question lets say the text string is "jhonSmith" I would like to get the hexadecimal representation of this string. using a sql server simple select statement.  I do not have access to create or call procedures on the database. 
this is the best ive been able to come up with but it returns blank. If i take the convert function off then it works.

```
select distinct convert (varbinary, dim_employee.full_name) as Employee
from dim_employee
where 1=1
```

if i use varchar instead of varbinary i get the data back something leads me to believe im not doing it correctly. Can someone point me in the right direction. Please!!!

Comment: You have a typo: `disctinct` -> `distinct`

Comment: Where exactly are you trying (and failing) to see the varbinary results?

Comment: thank you i did notice the typo.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When I run the following

```
select distinct convert (varbinary, 'Hogan') as Employee
```

I get the following

```
Employee
--------------------------------------------------------------
0x486F67616E
```

Maybe there is a problem in the way you are displaying the results?

Comment: thank you you were right. I was not displaying correctly sorry for my noobness.